# Adding Information from Table to Another

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

```
REPLACE INTO ytuser (id, yt1, yt2, yt3) SELECT DISTINCT userid, yt1, yt2, yt3 FROM ytid WHERE userid BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
```

Hello, So I have made this SQL to convert information from a table to another though after using this SQL it deleted the old information but it inserts what I need..
I want the query to only replace/update old 'yt1-yt2-yt3' according to id in 'ytuser' which is 'userid' in 'ytid'.

Comment: table in which you want the insert , is this new table or existing table?.

Comment: insert ... on duplicate key update ... ?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: they both existing tables @ishantkaushik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need an a update and not an insert then in MySQL
you could try using update with join.

```
UPDATE ytuser 
INNER JOIN ytid ON ytuser.id=ytid.userid
SET 
ytuser.yt1 =ytid.yt1,
ytuser.yt2 =ytid.yt2,
ytuser.yt3= ytid.yt3
WHERE ytid.userid BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE INTO ytuser (id, username, yt1, yt2, yt3, ytpoints, premium, ytinfo)
SELECT userid, username, yi.yt1, yi.yt2, yi.yt3, yu.ytpoints, yu.premium, yu.ytinfo FROM ytuser yu
INNER JOIN ytid yi
ON yi.userid = yu.id
WHERE yi.userid BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
```

This is the answer ( credits : Tok124 )

Answer (score 0):

```
Update ytuser set 
ytuser.yt1=ytid.yt1,ytuser.yt2=ytid.yt2,ytuser.yt3= ytid.yt3
From ytuser 
inner join ytid 
on ytuser.id=ytid.userid
where ytid.userid between 1 to 10000;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your solution.